# CQ5 checkboxes false

Tags: checkbox, adobe, selection, aem

I would like to have it where i can only select one checkbox at a time and when selected show the textfield associated with the selection. At least have it where i can only select one checkbox at a time. I have setup the dialog to run a choose when statement when for the selections but only want to select one at a time.

Comment: Would a Radio Group work for you, instead of a Checkbox Group?

Answer (score 1):

You can use listeners to react to user actions [e.g.: dynamic dialogs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/widgets.html#Dynamic%20Dialogs), however you probably want to use radios.